# How to get colums side by side on large screens and under each other on smaller screens in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two columns within a row, but they're not side by side. They are within another div column that is within another row, but that shouldn't matter, should it? Columns should always be side by side unless coded otherwise. How can I make sure the columns are next to each other in larger screens and underneath each other on smaller screens? I tried the order-* tag, but that didn't work. I'm only a beginner, so apologies is this is easy to fix, but I can't figure it out myself.

It looks like this now, the text should be next to the picture on the right side:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSMxr.png)

This is the code:

```css
.recept-bereiding {
 color: #9a084d;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

.recept-bereiding p {
 font-size: 0.85rem !important;
}

.steps { 
 padding-left: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #9a084d;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 counter-reset: step-counter calc(var(--start) - 1);
}

.steps img {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.steps ol {
 counter-reset: step-counter;
}

.steps li {
 counter-increment: step-counter;
 counter-reset: none;
}

.steps li::before {
 content: counter(step-counter);
 background-color: #7dc623;
 margin-right: 5px;
 padding: 4px 8px;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #ffffff;
 border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container ">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-md-8 recept-bereiding">
    <h3>Omschrijving</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed finibus odio id augue ornare scelerisque. Quisque porta tempor velit, in viverra urna euismod in. Nulla nec efficitur turpis. Quisque at.</p>
    <h3>Bereidingswijze</h3>
    <row>
     <div class="col-md-3 p-0 steps">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SJAUllt.jpg" alt=""/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-9 p-0">
      <ol style="counter-reset: step-counter 0" start="1" class="steps">
       <li>Vestibulum rhoncus egestas lectus quis vulputate. Vestibulum rutrum, ipsum vel vestibulum suscipit, sem lorem malesuada ex, a.</li>
      </ol>
     </div>
    </row>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 receptside">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried the following but that doesn't work either, I'm at loss:

`@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:767px) {
.stepsbox {
 display: block !important;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:2000px){
.stepsbox {
 display: inline !important;
 }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well,

> Columns should always be side by side unless coded otherwise

isn't always true and it depends on the viewport dimensions.
I would code it like this :

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 recept-bereiding">
                    <h3>Omschrijving</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed finibus odio id augue ornare scelerisque. Quisque porta tempor velit, in viverra urna euismod in. Nulla nec efficitur turpis. Quisque at.</p>
                    <h3>Bereidingswijze</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 p-0 steps">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SJAUllt.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 p-0">
                    <ol style="counter-reset: step-counter 0" start="1" class="steps">
                        <li>Vestibulum rhoncus egestas lectus quis vulputate. Vestibulum rutrum, ipsum vel vestibulum suscipit, sem lorem malesuada ex, a.</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 receptside">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

consider the following points:

1. Do not use row tag in your html. row is a bootstrap class and must be treated as

```
<div class="row">
```

2. ending tags do not need classes as in:

```
</div class="row">
```

3. use bootstrap responsive numbers accordingly.

```
<div class="col-md-4"
```

means it will occupy 4 parts of the 12 available space given to its div on a medium sized screen

Comment: Oh wow, I confused it with HTML5, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Can change `<row>` to `<div class="row">`. When in fullscreen, the column will show side by side.

```css
.recept-bereiding {
 color: #9a084d;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

.recept-bereiding p {
 font-size: 0.85rem !important;
}

.steps { 
 padding-left: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #9a084d;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 counter-reset: step-counter calc(var(--start) - 1);
}

.steps img {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.steps ol {
 counter-reset: step-counter;
}

.steps li {
 counter-increment: step-counter;
 counter-reset: none;
}

.steps li::before {
 content: counter(step-counter);
 background-color: #7dc623;
 margin-right: 5px;
 padding: 4px 8px;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #ffffff;
 border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container ">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-md-8 recept-bereiding">
    <h3>Omschrijving</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed finibus odio id augue ornare scelerisque. Quisque porta tempor velit, in viverra urna euismod in. Nulla nec efficitur turpis. Quisque at.</p>
    <h3>Bereidingswijze</h3>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 p-0 steps">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SJAUllt.jpg" alt=""/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-9 p-0">
      <ol style="counter-reset: step-counter 0" start="1" class="steps">
       <li>Vestibulum rhoncus egestas lectus quis vulputate. Vestibulum rutrum, ipsum vel vestibulum suscipit, sem lorem malesuada ex, a.</li>
      </ol>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 receptside">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```